# What is better DECIMAL or may INT (BIGINT), to represent the amounts in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a table and I keep in it prices in different currencies.

I know that I can't use floating point numbers.

I wonder whether to store them in a `DECIMAL` or `INT` (`BIGINT`).

More convenient is to use `DECIMAL`, but the calculations performed by the database may be safer to use `INT`? Then, of course, in the result is divided by the appropriate power of ten...

I think about operations like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE total_price / quantity > price
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, but if there is a difference with the Postgresql then I want to know about it also.

Comment: some articals on this 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696377/mysql-bigint-or-decimal-for-storing-32-bit-values-but-less-than-64-bits 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682115/decimal-vs-int-in-mysql I would go for decimal we also save a lot of premium histories and found it works better.

Comment: What makes you think an integer is "safer" than a decimal? And what does *safer* mean?

Comment: As for the correct results of the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, and for this they will be rounding. Mainly it comes to rounding in the background during such operations.

Comment: That seems to tell us what you *want*, but not *why* you think an integer is "safer" than a decimal.

Comment: The idea is that dividing in numbers with comma may be flawed, and integers can, for example, to perform integer division and consider the rest of the division. Then, completely we eliminate errors associated with the approximation, but complicate realize computationally...

Comment: A general rule when creating your database should be to make your data as clea[r|n] as possible. But if you really really want to use `int`, use it, it's just a/your choice. Just be prepared for things like countries that don't use 2 decimals. Technically, both solutions will behave the same (including auto rounding). If they don't, you found a bug. Send it to the developers. To decide what's "safer", you have to evaluate if it's more likely for you (or your colleague or successor) to forget a conversion somewhere in your code, or for a library used by a whole lot of users to contain a bug.

Comment: @simhumileco: I think you have SQL `decimal(p, s)` and `numeric(p, s)` data types confused with floating point data types.